# Reduce array of objects into object of arrays

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects where each object has two keys: key (`k`) and value (`v`). I need to make an object that would take values of `k` and collect corresponding values of `v` as a value of this key, an array of them.

So, for example, from an array

```
[{
  k: 'a',
  v: 0
}, {
  k: 'a',
  v: 1
}, {
  k: 'b',
  v: 2
}]
```

I need an object

```
{
  a: [0, 1],
  b: [2]
}
```

It's easy to use outer-scope variables but what I want to do is to perform it in functional manner.

Right now, I have this piece of (ES6) code:

```
rows.reduce((result, item) => ({
  ...result,
  [item.k]: [
    ...(result[item.k] || []),
    item.v
  ]}),
{});
```

It works nice but the question is if it is possible to optimize it in terms of SLOC. For one, I don't like the `...(result[item.k] || [])` piece but if I leave it as simple as `...result[item.k]` then I get an error because, when it's undefined, babel fails to perform a method call of it, since undefined doesn't have any methods.

Did I maybe take a wrong path and there's a more elegant solution that reducing the array?

I would appreciate any suggestions, please throw any ideas at me.

Comment: Btw, object spread is ES7, not ES6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We've got a readability issue here. This is the horror we all have to face when we overuse the new "concise" ES6 syntax. I had to read the code at least 3 times to understand what it was doing (and forgot `...` is spread).

If you're worried about code size, *let the minifier do its job*. Code is for programmers to understand. The verbose version of it isn't that bad. It's not like it's not going to run in older browsers.

```
var result = rows.reduce(function(result, item){
  result[item.k] = (result[item.k] || []).concat(item);
  return result;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are a fan of FP, you should use a functional library, e. g. Ramda. With it, you can create your transforming function points-free style:

```
import { compose, mapObj, map, prop, groupBy } from 'ramda';

const f = compose(
  mapObj(
    map(prop('v'))
  ),
  groupBy(prop('k'))
);
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/03m7r7be/

Comment: If you like this answer most, you should accept it (there is a button to the left).